# deleting a favorite file from Windows Media Player

Tags: playlists

I have Windows 7 and am just learning about organizing music files in Media Player.  If I delete a playlist file I created, does it delete the songs from "Music"?

Comment: Playlist = list with links to files and their tags. So no, you wont delete files if you delete your playlist

Answer (score 0):

No the playlist is simply a text file that contains links to your media files and deleting that text file will not delete your music!